# Creating a HTTP request for Windows phone 8 C++/CX

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8

I need to create simple HTTP request with Windows Phone 8 C++/CX. Where could I find an example?

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956(v=vs.105).aspx document says `IXMLHTTPRequest2` should be supported but I have no idea how to enable it in my project. It is just a standard Windows phone Direct3d native app?

Comment: emh it seems i was including wrong header file to get xml http request 2 to work. well still looking for good examples how to use that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft's example for IXMLHTTPRequest2, worked for me in windows phone 8 c++/cx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873181.aspx 
The only changed I needed to do, was for CreateStreamOverRandomAccessStream which is not implemented in WP8.
Rewrite this method:

```
void HttpRequest::CreateMemoryStream(IStream **stream)
{
   auto randomAccessStream = ref new Windows::Storage::Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
   CheckHResult(CreateStreamOverRandomAccessStream(randomAccessStream, IID_PPV_ARGS(stream)));
}
```

To this:

```
void HttpRequest::CreateMemoryStream(IStream** stream)
{   
    checkHResult(::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, stream));
}
```

Comment: The link appears to be non-functional, as the code samples no longer render (broken links, maybe).  Do you have working code that you can add directly to your answer?  If so, would you please add it?  Thanks!